# Producing XLS File in Node

Tags: javascript, node.js, excel, xls

I am trying to edit an XLS template in Node - specifically the file needs to be written as an XLS, not an XLSX. There seems to be many libraries available for managing this in XLSX, but I've not managed to find anything that allows the opening, editing, and writing of an XLS file.

The validation on the XLS file once it is written is fairly tight, so it would be preferable to open the template and write the data to it, rather than reproducing from scratch.

Does anyone know of any options?  I've searched high and low, asking here is my last resort before having to produce in a different language.

Comment: xls templates have the xlt extension. Are you trying to write XLT files or XLS ?

Comment: I'm trying to write to an XLS. Sorry, perhaps my question was misleading, the original file is an XLS, needs editing, and saving as an XLS.  I shall update the wording.

Comment: ok. Did you try [sheet.js](https://github.com/sheetjs/js-xlsx)? It supports a number of formats including XLS